# Use vba to write formula in cell

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, formula

My basic formula is : `=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,$A2)=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,$B2),"OK","NOT OK")`

I use it to know if there are duplicate in column A, and i check the value in B.

```
ID    Age   My formula

1     15    NOT OK
2     50    OK
2     50    OK
3     35    OK
1     15    NOT OK
1     16    NOT OK
```

Now i'd like to write it with VBA, so I record a maccro, select the cell, press F2 then press Enter. I get:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
 "=IF(COUNTIF(C3,RC[-10])=COUNTIFS(C3,RC[-10],C12,RC[-1]),""PRODUIT"",""ARTICLE"")"
```

Alright, it work. Now I'd like to use this formula with a new column:

```
Id    Age   Age formula   Money   Money formula   Value3   Value3 formula   ...

1     15    NOT OK        150     OK              ...      ...
2     50    OK            5       NOT OK          ...
2     50    OK            800     NOT OK
3     35    OK            80      OK
1     15    NOT OK        150     OK
1     16    NOT OK        150     OK
```

I know how to use the formular "by hand" and I know how to use it for a single cell in vba, but I don´t know hot to use it in a loop. (I have to use the formula on 25+ column that's why I need loop and variable)

Sorry for my bad english,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to edit the 25 in `For r = 2 To 25` to the last row you want to fill with the formula.

Code:

```
'Loops throug the rows
For r = 2 To 25
    'Loops throug the columns
    For c = 13 To 69 Step 2
        'Converts the column-index into the column-letter
        Dim col As String
        col = Split(Cells(r, c - 1).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        'Writes the formula into the cell
        Cells(r, c).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF($C:$C,C" & r & ")=COUNTIFS($C:$C,C" & r & ",$" & col & ":$" & col & "," & col & r & "),""PRODUIT"",""ARTICLE"")"
    Next
Next
```

Comment: No problem mate :)

Comment: i'd like to up your answer but i d'ont have enough reputation! :(

Comment: No problem since you accepted it as answer ^^ I think you earn the right tu upvote with about 20 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you tony for your time.

So:

1. my excel file has A to BQ column
2. from L to BQ, one out of two colum is data, and the next is the formula
3. My ID is always column C
4. basically M column will use column C to check the ID and column L to check the value.

Now the formulas:
cell M2 with Excel:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C:$C;C2)=COUNTIFS($C:$C;C2;$L:$L;L2);"PRODUIT";"ARTICLE")
```

Cell M2 with VBA:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _    "=IF(COUNTIF(C3,RC[-10])=COUNTIFS(C3,RC[-10],C12,RC[-1]),""PRODUIT"",""ARTICLE"")"`

Now cell O2 (based on C and N columns) in Excel:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C:$C;C2)=COUNTIFS($C:$C;C2;$N:$N;N2);"PRODUIT";"ARTICLE")
```

Finally cell O2 with VBA:

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(COUNTIF(C3,RC[-12])=COUNTIFS(C3,RC[-12],C14,RC[-1]),""PRODUIT"",""ARTICLE"")"
```

Now i'd like to use a loop (from L to BQ with step 2) to fill M2, O2, Q2, S2... with variable

I hope you get it this time,
sorry again for my low english level

Comment: I tried to replace [-10] by [-" variable "] and [-12] by [-" variable +2 "] but it doesn't work